# rounding corners of textview android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The following codes do not round the corners of textview in my app..

Here's my res/drawable/round_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="14dp" />

</shape>
```

Here's my layout.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/menu1" android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="60dp" android:text="@string/capleaf"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textview is round. But you don't see it because there is no border color. How do you know it's not round?  ;)

Add the following in round_corners.xml:

```
<stroke 
    android:color="#ffffff"
    android:width="2dp"/>
```

It will give a border to your textview.